# Output voltage for this OP-AMP circuit

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier

I need to derive the output expression for this circuit in terms of ui1, ui2 and ui3. I am stuck on this for hours and have an exam next week.

So far,
I was able to get the sum of 3 voltages. I also know the part after R2 is a non-inverting amplifier. I am unable to get the voltage across the R2 which would serve as input to the noninverting amplifier. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: For homework assignments show the efforts you put in yourself to solve this.

Comment: I figured out the output of A1, A2, A3 as they are voltage follower circuits. I am unable to proceed further as I am not able to deal with input at both terminals as well as the arrangement of resistors to the inverting terminal.

Comment: Ok, so here's a hint, that hopefully leads you on the right track: the 3 R1's together with R2 are passive voltage dividers. You can use the superposition principal with the outputs of the buffers as sources to derive the voltage across R2. Afterwards this voltage is the input of the last stage. Google non-inverting amplifier should lead you on the right track for that one.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Good luck and good luck with the exam next week! 

Comment: Vin4+=31 so what is loss to Vin+

Comment: @letsfetz Can the sum of the 3 opamp voltages be treated as a summing amplifier?

Comment: No. It cannot. It is a passive network and when connecting passive networks, they interfere (therefore superposition) with each other. Active circuits keep the inputs appart from each other.

Comment: Here is a hint. Once you know the current across R2, you also know the voltage at the non-inverting input.

Comment: @EasyOhm Thanks I figured that out. I am not able to find the current across R2

Comment: Edit your question to show your efforts so far.

Answer (score 0):

As this is looks like homework these are just hints.

Let's call the voltage at the non inverting input of \$A_4\$  \$ x \$.

You already know that \$ A_1 \$, \$ A_2 \$ and \$ A_3 \$ are voltage followers so need to find \$ x \$.

From Kirchoff's current law we know that the sum of currents into any node is zero, i.e. what flows in must flow out, and the inputs to an op-amp take no current so.

$$ \dfrac{u_{11}-x}{R_1} + \dfrac{u_{12}-x}{R_1} + \dfrac{u_{13}-x}{R_1} + \dfrac{-x}{R_2} = 0$$

Can you find \$ x \$ from here?
Let's call the voltage at the inverting input of \$ A_4 \$ \$ y \$ what should it be?

Clue: \$ A_4 \$ has gain \$ G \$ and \$ G \$ can be taken to be very large.

The output voltage \$ u_o = G \cdot (x - y) \$ unless the amplifier saturates then it is limited by the supply rails.

What does \$ u_o \$ need to be to make this the case?

Comment: I found x.

The input at inverting input should be -x?

Comment: I've edited the question to provide a clue to this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the use of an ideal opamp a [voltage follower (unity buffer amplifier)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier_applications#Voltage_follower_(unity_buffer_amplifier)) has the same input as output voltage. So we are analyzing the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8rzj4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff's_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_0=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\text{I}_0+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_8=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_7\\
\\
\text{I}_8=\text{I}_4+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\text{I}_6
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [KVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff's_voltage_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_\text{y}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_\text{z}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\frac{\text{V}_4-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_6}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_0=\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_\text{y}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_\text{y}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}=\text{I}_0+\frac{\text{V}_\text{z}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_8=\frac{\text{V}_\text{z}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}+\text{I}_7\\
\\
\text{I}_8=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}+\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_5}=\frac{\text{V}_4-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_6}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, when we have an ideal opamp we know that \$\text{V}_\alpha:=\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-=\text{V}_1=\text{V}_3\$. So we can rewrite equation \$(3)\$ as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_0=\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}-\text{V}_\alpha}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_\text{y}-\text{V}_\alpha}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}-\text{V}_\alpha}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_\text{y}-\text{V}_\alpha}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_\alpha-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}=\text{I}_0+\frac{\text{V}_\text{z}-\text{V}_\alpha}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_8=\frac{\text{V}_\text{z}-\text{V}_\alpha}{\text{R}_3}+\text{I}_7\\
\\
\text{I}_8=\frac{\text{V}_\alpha-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}+\frac{\text{V}_\alpha-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_\alpha-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_5}=\frac{\text{V}_4-\text{V}_\alpha}{\text{R}_6}
\end{cases}\tag4
$$

Now, when \$\text{R}_\text{T}:=\text{R}_1=\text{R}_2=\text{R}_3\$ and \$\text{R}_4=\text{R}_6=10\text{R}_\text{T}\$, the output voltage simplifies to:

$$\text{V}_4=\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}+\text{V}_\text{y}+\text{V}_\text{z}}{3}\tag{5}$$